# swift 4 label that each time i hit the button the label shows a different word

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a label that when a I hit a button the label displays different words. Like the label gets the data from an array or something. I tried this code but I don't want my label to show random words. I just want the words in order.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var funFactLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var showButton: UIButton!

    var factProvider = FactProvider()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        funFactLabel.text = factProvider.randomFact()
    }

    @IBAction func showFact() {
        funFactLabel.text = factProvider.randomFact()

        let newColor = BackgroundColorProvider.randomColor()
        view.backgroundColor = newColor
        showButton.tintColor = newColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is both too vague and too broad. Moe's answer is as good as any.

Comment: Post the code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array first:

```
let creatures = ["Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Butterfly", "Fish"]
```

And add an `IBOutlet` for your label:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

And add an `IBAction` for your button:

```
@IBAction func updateLabelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Get the index of a random element from the array
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(creatures.count)))

    // Set the text at the randomIndex as the text of the label
    label.text = creatures[randomIndex]
}
```

**Edit:**

If you wanted to show the words in order, then add a new property to your class to save the current index:

```
private var currentIndex = 0
```

And replace your `IBAction` with the following:

```
@IBAction func updateLabelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    label.text = creatures[currentIndex] // Set the text to the element at currentIndex in the array
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1 == creatures.count ? 0 : currentIndex + 1 // Increment currentIndex
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to show the words in order not random can you help me please ?

Comment: @Dairon Check my updated answer. Good luck!